# Display a frame when a button is clicked

Tags: delphi, events, delphi-7, frame

I'm trying to do a simple program that will display a frame when a button on an other frame/form is clicked. To be more clear I want something like a MessageDialogBox but instead of a MessageDialogBox I want to display a frame.

What I've tried so far is this code on then OnClickEvent.

```
procedure TFrame3.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
    frm : TfrmVizorFunctii; // This is the frame I want to be appear;  
begin
    frm := TfrmVizorFunctii.Create(nil);
    frm.Parent := nil;
    frm.ABDBGrid1.ActiveColumn:=2;
    frm.Left:=(Screen.Width-Width)  div 2;
    frm.Top:=(Screen.Height-Height) div 2;
    frm.Show;


end;
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since the frame has no parent, it will be invisible. Try with `frm.Parent := Self` instead.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand if I do this, it will display my frame, but the frame is displayed on my parent frame, I don't want this, I want it to be independent.

Comment: Technically you can redeclare 'Show' to call 'ShowWindow' and override 'CreateParams' to remove the child flag. But then what you'll end up will be a form with a lot of problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot display a frame without a parent. You must either set an existing form (or any `TWinControl` on that form) as the parent, or create a new empty form and set that as the parent like so:

```
Form := TEmptyForm.Create (Application);
Frame := TMyFrame.Create (Form);
Frame.Parent := Form;
Frame.Align := alClient;
Form.Show;
```

That `TEmptyForm` could have `BorderStyle` set to `bsNone` if you really only want to display the frame.

Comment: Thanks! It works like this. but now I wonder if there is an advantage in using a Frame for thinks like this or simply use the Form.

Comment: If you always use it this way, I would just use a form. The frame only brings advantages if you want to reuse the same UI on several forms.

Comment: I agree with jpfollenius. For example you can use a main form and two frames: one for showing a group of record (a DBGrid) and the second to show the details of the choosen record.